# How to find if element exists in document - MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to check my collection to return all documents where an element of the array in the document is a certain value.

For example, here is one of my documents JSON:

```
[
{
    "employer" : "employer1@gmail.com",
    "applicants" : [
        {
            "email" : "joe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "email" : "fred@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "employer" : "employer2@gmail.com",
    "applicants" : [
        {
            "email" : "steven@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "employer" : "employer3@gmail.com",
}
]
```

Now, what I would like returned is any document where the applicants array does not contain the email `"steven@gmail.com"` OR where there is `no applicants array`.

In my example JSON above, it should return the documents for `employer1` and `employer2`.

I have gotten as far as to return the documents where the applicant `steven@gmail.com does not exist`, so employer1, but I don't understand how I can also include the `employer3`. How can I do this?

This is my query so far in JavaScript:

```
collection.find({"applicants.email" : {$ne : req.user.username}}, {}, function(e,docs){
            res.json(docs);
            console.log(docs);
    });
```

Comment: Use $elemMatch to find object in array  like this `{ applicants:{ $elemMatch: { email :{ $ne:req.user.email }}}}`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it returns []. If I add "applicants" : [] to my document, the original query I had works, but I don't think I should have to add a blank array to get this working should I?

Comment: Hmm weird, I can't test it now. Then try the original query like this `{ $or: [{"applicants: $or: [{ $exists: false}, {$size: 0}] ,{"applicants.email" : {$ne : req.user.username}]}` this should return documents where the applicants array doesn't exist or is empty or the email is not req.user.username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query, which may help you:-

Refer [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) for more info on how to use it.

This query will return results, if `applicants.email` not equal to `req.user.username` OR if `applicants` array size is 0.

```
collection.find({$or:[
                     {"applicants.email" : {$ne : req.user.username}},
                     {applicants: {$size: 0}}
                 }], function(e,docs){
        console.log(docs);
});
```

I never tried the query. Let me know if it is giving any error.

Also you can try out this one:-

This query will return results, if `applicants.email` not equal to `req.user.username` OR if `applicants` array is not present.

```
 collection.find({$or:[
                     {"applicants.email" : {$ne : req.user.username}},
                     {applicants: {$exists: false}}
                 }], function(e,docs){
        console.log(docs);
});
```

Refer [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) for more info.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! I had come up with the second option that you posted as well and that worked!

Comment: Glad to help you!! Can you upvote the answer if it helped? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
collection.find({applicants: {$not: {$size: 0}}},function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Applicats Array Where size is not zero:");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this query ,  `$nin` is useful for this condition

```
collection.find({"applicants.email" : {$nin:["steven@gmail.com"]}}, {}, function(e,docs){
            res.json(docs);
            console.log(docs);
    });
```